# Authentication process for Mifare Ultralight C using PN532

Tags: authentication, nfc, rfid, mifare

We know the process for Authentication to Mifare Ultralight C but we cannot do the authentication using PN532 chip. We follow the steps as shown in the commands sets but we can't get the exact result. We need some help to do the authentication process for Mifare Ultralight C. Please give some suggestion  or anybody worked on this card can help.

#### Discover tag and get UID

```
Command:  00 00 FF 05 FB D4 60 01 01 00 CA 00
Response: 00 00 ff 11 ef d5 61 01 10 0c 01 00 44 00 07 04 54 ad f2 ef 45 80 b6 00
```

#### Start authentication (Auth0)

```
Command:  00 00 FF 04 FC D4 42 1A 00 D0 00
Response: 00 00 ff 0c f4 d5 43 00 af 22 f5 ec 57 19 7f 44 72 91 00
```

Decrypt RndB and rotate to RndB':

```
Key =                49454D4B41455242214E4143554F5946
enc(RndB) =          22 f5 ec 57 19 7f 44 72
decrypt(enc(RndB)) = d1 f4 00 d1 13 bd ef 04
RndB' =              04 f4 00 d1 13 bd ef d1
```

Generate RndA and build RndA || RndB':

```
RndA =          74 bd 85 75 7b d2 8b 77
RndA || RndB' = 74 bd 85 75 7b d2 8b 77   04 f4 00 d1 13 bd ef d1
```

Encrypt RndA || RndB':

```
IV = 22F5EC57197F4472
encrypt(RndA || RndB') = 98 70 67 11 40 8F 73 B1 1C 11 15 6A 30 47 ED 58
```

#### Second authentication step (Auth1)

Now we have to pass this `encrypt(RndA || RndB')` to the card using AFh Mifare Ultralight C command like this:

```
Command:  00 00 FF 13 ED D4 42 AF 98 70 67 11 40 8F 73 B1 1C 11 15 6A 30 47 ED 58 60 00
Response: 00 00 ff 03 fd d5 43 01 e7 00
```

This results in the error code 01h.

Comment: 1st step UID :   00 00 FF 05 FB D4 60 01 01 00 CA 00   response:

Comment: Hi Roland,  I edited the Main question itself please check and please give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you rotate RndB into the wrong direction. If you have a RndB like

```
RndB = decrypt(enc(RndB)) = d1 f4 00 d1 13 bd ef 04
```

then RndB' should be

```
RndB' = rotate_left(RndB) = f4 00 d1 13 bd ef 04 d1
```

Comment: I am using following APDU, to (Auth0):
FF00000004D4421A00
But receive:
D543019000, until I try 4 to 5 times then it succeeds, can you please help me out on this one?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: Third byte in the response is the 'status' byte, and 0x01 stands for 'TimeOut'. Details at section 7 in PN532 User Manual (http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/141520.pdf)